# Who was the earliest Sudra king?

Tags: shudra, kings

Was it the Rig Vedic king Sudas?  He is said to have fought in the battle of ten kings.

Answer (score 4):

> Who was the earliest Sudra king?

**The first Shudra king existed in Kali Yuga. Shudras being kings is a symptom of Kali Yuga.**

From the *[Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp156.htm#page_621)* on the symptoms of Kali Yuga:

> In the Kali age every one who has cars and elephants and steeds will
>   be a Rájá.

From the [*Bhagavata Purana*](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/1/37/) on the degraded dynasties of Kali Yuga:

> **12.1.37** - The land along the Sindhu River, as well as the districts of
>   Candrabhāgā, Kauntī and Kāśmīra, **will be ruled by śūdras**, fallen
>   brāhmaṇas and Mlecchas. Having given up the path of Vedic
>   civilization, they will have lost all spiritual strength.

Comment: this does not answer who he was:)

Comment: BTW could not the vishnu puran predict that all brahmins in kali yuga will be fallen?According to Smriti,every brahmin living under mlechcha rule is fallen:)

Comment: This does not answer the question! Its flagged as low quality!

Comment: This is a partial answer, so it should be edited (says that Sudas wasn't the first shudra king)

Comment: I think Mahapadma Nanda